# DataGridView Selected Column in CellEndEdit Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, reentrancy

Example code below:

```
Private Sub dgIndividualStores_CellEndEdit(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgIndividualStores.CellEndEdit

    'Code Here + Error Checking

    If error Then
        dgIndividualStores.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = ""
        dgIndividualStores.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Ok, so when the user enters invalid data into the cell, and then navigates to a different cell, the selected statement in this event causes there to be two selected cells, the erroneous cell + the newly selected cell are both selected.

I tried setting the

```
dgIndividualStores.MultiSelect = False
```

but seen as the DGV is already working with something in this current column, it needs to be the column selected as well otherise it throws a "**Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function**" Error.

*When the user navigates away from this cell and there is an error, how can I select only the cell with the error, instead of both? Is it even possible with this event?*

Comment: why not use the validation events to validate?

Comment: As @Plutonix suggests, if you want to validate a cell then you should be handling `CellValidating`, not `CellEndEdit`.

Comment: Will using CellValidating resolve my issue?